Отладка WASM проекта в CLion или QtCreator
Есть pet project для WebAssembly с использованием vcpkg.
Для написания кода использую CLion.
Компиляцию под WASM я настроил. Проект собирается и запускается в node.js из командной строки.
Как теперь настроить запуск и отладку прямо из IDE?
Интересуют настройки CLion/QtCreator, но и для других IDE подойдет.
UPD0: с запуском в CLion разобрался:

в интерфейсе нужно найти target
вызвать контекстное меню
выбрать Run или Debug - создастся конфигурация запуска и приложение запустится

Но это про отладку и запуск JavaScript. С отладкой WebAsm пока не понятно.

Я знаю только что можно дебажить в браузере. С FF были какие-то проблемы, а в хроме так:

Поставить официальное расширение: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cc++-devtools-support-dwa/pdcpmagijalfljmkmjngeonclgbbannb

Включить его: в панели разработчика, кнопка с шестеренкой -> Experiments -> WebAssembly Debugging: Enable DWARF support (включается автоматически?)

Код должен быть сбилжен с -g.

Запускам через emrun имя.html (или, по идее, любой другой http-сервер может срабоать). Если дефолтный браузер - не хром, добавляем к emrun флаг --browser=chrome.


После перезагрузки страницы в консоли должно вылезти сообщение, что дебажные символы успешно загружены. В списке файлов (под file://) будут видны плюсовые исходники, а в дебаггере - работать брейкпоинты и прочее.

Работает в текущих версиях Chrome/Chromium. Включать расширение в DevTools не нужно - там нет этой опции. Для доступа к исходникам нужно добавить директорию с проектом в DevTools.

@MaximTimakov Спасибо, поправил. Про добавление директории - хз, у меня и так взлетело.

Добавлю: Отладка WebASM работает в браузере "из коробки". Это расширение нужно чтобы видеть исходники а не ассемблерный листинг.
